# Passar array de javascript para php com recurso a ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Bom dia pessoal. 
Estou aqui com uma duvida num trabalho de php/jquery e queria que voces me ajudassem

Num ficheiro javascript eu tenho este codigo aqui

```html
var categorias;
var categoria;
var array = [];




$(document).ready(function(){
 $.getJSON("Categorias.php", function(dados){
  categorias = dados;
  $.each(categorias, function(index, categoria){
                    
                   // var a = array.indexOf(categoria);
                    //if(a==-1){
                          array.push(categoria);
                      //}
                      
  });
                filtrar();
 }); 
});


function filtrar(){
            
            var variavel;
            for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                variavel = "<input type='checkbox' name='categorias' checked value='"+array[i].categoria+"' class='opcoes'/>"+array[i].categoria+"<br />";
                $("#filtro").append(variavel);
            }
            $("#ver").click(function(){
                array=[];
                $(".opcoes").each(function(index, check){
                   if($(check).prop('checked')){
                       array.push($(check).attr("value"));
                   }
                });
               alert("Você escolheu as seguintes categorias: " + array);
                });
                
                
            $("#todas").click(function(){
                array=[];
                $(".opcoes").each(function(index, check){
                   if($(check).prop('checked')){
                   }
                   else{
                       $(check).prop('checked', true);
                   }
                });
                });
                
                
            $("#remove").click(function(){
                array=[];
                
                $(".opcoes").each(function(index, check){
                   if($(check).prop('checked')){
                        $(check).prop('checked', false);
                   }
                });
                });
        }
```

e agora eu queria passar a variavel array para a minha pagina php só que não estou conseguindo

```html
function(array)
   {
      $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
      url: "load_post.php",
   data: {categoria : array},
      success: function(dados){
          alert(dados);
   $('#load_post').html(dados);
      }
    });
      
   }
```

na minha variavel array eu tenho o nome das categorias, então eu queria que esta funçao recebesse esse array, o transformasse em string para que eu depois o pudesse usar numa query para ir buscar as informaçoes daquela categoria...

no load_post.php tenho isto

```html
<?php


$ligacao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "publicidades");
                        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                            echo "Erro na liga��o MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                        }
                        
                        
                        $sql_img = "SELECT * FROM publicidade WHERE id_publicidade  > 0 and estado = 1 AND categoria in ('".$_POST['categoria']."') ORDER BY visualizacoes DESC";
                        $imagem = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql_img);
                        $objeto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($imagem);
                        $attempts = $objeto["descricao"];
                        $estado = $objeto["estado"];
                        
                        $visu = "SELECT visualizacoes FROM publicidade WHERE id_publicidade ='".$objeto["id_publicidade"]."'";
                        $obj = mysqli_query($ligacao, $visu);
                        $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($obj);
                        $final = $res["visualizacoes"];
                        
                        
                        $num_post = mysqli_num_rows($imagem);


if( $num_post ) {
    if($estado){
                if($final>0){
                echo "<img src=\"$attempts\" alt=\"Não deu!!\">";
                $alterar = "UPDATE publicidade SET visualizacoes  = visualizacoes-1 WHERE descricao = '$attempts'";
                $alteracao =  mysqli_query($ligacao, $alterar);
                }else{
                    echo 'O seu tempo de antena acabou';
                }
                }   
} else {
   echo '<p>Já não existem mais imagens.</p>';
}

?>
```

Aqui eu queria usar a tal variavel que chega para a introduzir na query

Categoria.php

```html
<?php

$ligacao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","publicidades");
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Erro na liga??o MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }


$sql = "select distinct categoria from publicidade";

   $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql);
   
$array_publicidades = array();

   while( ($registo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) !=null)
   {
  $array_registo['categoria'] = $registo['categoria'];
  
                array_push($array_publicidades,$array_registo);
   }    
   
   echo json_encode($array_publicidades);
?>
```

Aqui eu crio um json com as varias categorias das publicidades

Comment: O que te chega ao PHP quando fazes `var_dump($_POST['categoria']);`?

Comment: Undefined index: categoria in C:\xampp\htdocs\RAFA\load_post.php on line 39
NULL

Comment: Podes colocar o código desse `load_post.php`?

Comment: Ja coloquei o codigo

Comment: Acho que a sua duvida seria a mesma aqui.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53896/enviar-objeto-javascript-para-php/53922#53922

Comment: Qual código do arquivo `Categoria.php`?

Comment: Ja atualizei essa parte, está no final

Comment: @Filipe: nesse `load_post.php` onde colocaste `var_dump($_POST['categoria']);`? não o vejo no código? e qual linha é essa linha 39 no código que mostraste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando usava PHP e precisava disso que está descrevendo eu montava uma string com todas as posições do array separadas com 2 pipes ex: campoa||campob||campoc||etc...
 Depois do lado js eu dava um split na mesma, como var.split("||"). dessa forma faz o array denovo no js e desta forma pode manipular os dados.

Comment: Exato, eu consegui fazer isso. Montei uma string com os dados todos e já deu para manipular.
Obrigado

Comment: boa, jovem! sucesso ai no php!