# Armazenar valores do onclick no banco de dados

Tags: jquery, ajax

Colegas,

Como faço para pegar o valor de um **onclick** e direcionar para uma outra página. Veja abaixo:

```
$('.value-plus').on('click', function(){    
    var lista = $('.invert > span');  
    $.each(lista, function(index,item){  
    valor = $(item).text();
    trocar = valor.replace(",",".");  

      e.preventDefault();
      var objeto = new Object();
      objeto.valor = trocar.toFixed(2);
      var dados= JSON.stringify(objeto);

     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         dataType: 'json',
         data: dados,
         url: "atualizar-carrinho.php",
         success: function(resposta){
           if (resposta) {
                alert("Sucesso!");
            } else {
                alert("Erro");
            }
        }
      });
     });
    });
```

No **atualizar-carrinho.php** estou pegando dessa forma:

```
<?php
   $conexao = (conexao ao banco de dados);
   $novoValor = $_GET['valor'];
   mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO teste VALUES(null,'".$novoValor."')");
```

Comment: Serialize a lista e envia no data! Dá pra usar como exemplo está resposta [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53896/enviar-objeto-javascript-para-php/53922#53922)

Comment: o que voce esta esperando receber no `atualizar-carrinho.php`? os valores separados por virgula? objetos?

Comment: Olá AndrePaulo. Os objetos. Preciso pegar a variável trocar.

Comment: Olá Marconi. Fiz uma alteração no meu post baseado no link que você me enviou, porém não está passando o valor...